# Feature extraction speech (Mel Frequency cepstral coefficient) in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, feature-extraction, mfcc

I'm currently trying to classify emotions (7 classes) based on audio files. The first thing I did was to extract the features using the mfcc function in the python_speech_features library (https://python-speech-features.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#functions-provided-in-python-speech-features-module).

In the documentation, it says that each row contains one feature vector. The problem is that each audio file returns a different number of rows (features) as the audio length is different. For example, for audio_1 the shape of the output is (155,13), for audio_2 the output's shape is (258,13). Any advice about how to make them the same shape? I am currently using PCA to force the data to have the same dimensionality, is this a correct approach?

This is how I extract the features:

```
sample_rate, data = wavfile.read(path)
mfccExtract = features.mfcc(data, sample_rate, winfunc=np.hamming)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each audio sample to be the same length, there are 4 different approaches that are available:

1. Zero Padding
2. N Modulo Reduction
3. Interpolation
4. Dynamic Time Wrapping

You can use any of them approach to each audio sample. These approaches are available in academic papers.